# Openbravo Integration with java Pos

Tags: java, openbravo, javapos

I'm trying to integrate Openbravo with there software Java pos, and I want to sync data from there server database to local POS Database.

So what I need to do is Download live database and replace local database with that.

or is there any option or tool which I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to download your live database and replace that one with your local database what you need to do is you need to use Pentaho Tool, this tool is supported by Openbravo and you can find it's wiki [here](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects:POS/ERP_Integration)

This tool will download data from Openbravo live database and Import tables automatically which is needed by the system